# Issue with MERN stack when data is coming back from Node

Tags: reactjs

I am using the Fetch API to post data to my Node server. There is behaviour that I am seeing which I am unable to understand and need some help in resolving. When the user clicks a button a modal opens up with a form with a few fields. On hitting submit, the data is passed to a node server. First it creates a new record for Mongo and saves the data in the collection. After saving I want to fetch some data from a few other collections and then send the information back to my react app.

Here is what I am seeing.

1. If i only save the data and don't do the fetching part and send back a message like this

   res.status(201).json({"message":"data received"})
   Then after the modal closes in my console I see the message "Data Received".
2. However if I do the fetch part, which basically means a few more milli seconds of delay, then once the modal closes, this message flashes in the react console.

   Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
   DOMException: The user aborted a request.

Here is my submit handler in react

```
const submitHandler = async(event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        try {
            const responseData = await sendRequest('http://localhost:5000/challenge/createChallenge', 'POST',
                JSON.stringify({
                    location: selectedOption,
                    format: selectedOption1,
                    date: selectedDate.toString(),
                    opponent: props.initialValues,
                    month: cMonth,
                    year: cYear,
                    player: auth.profile.MemberName
                }),
              {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.token
              })    
              console.log(responseData)
        } catch (err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

And here is my http-hook, which is a custom hook I am using

```
import { useState, useCallback, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

export const useHttpClient = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)

    const activeHttpRequests = useRef([])

    const sendRequest = useCallback(async (url, method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {}) => {

        setIsLoading(true)
        const httpAbortCtrl = new AbortController()
        activeHttpRequests.current.push(httpAbortCtrl)
       try {
        const response =  await fetch(url, {
            method,
            body,
            headers,
            signal: httpAbortCtrl.signal
        })

        const responseData = await response.json()
        activeHttpRequests.current = activeHttpRequests.current.filter(reqCtrl => reqCtrl !== httpAbortCtrl)
        if(!response.ok){
            throw new Error(responseData.message)
        }
        setIsLoading(false)
        return responseData

       } catch (err){
           setError(err.message)
           setIsLoading(false)
           throw err
       }
    }, [])

    const clearError = () => {
        setError(null)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            activeHttpRequests.current.forEach(abortCtrl => abortCtrl.abort())
        }
    }, [])

    return { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError}
}
```

Can some one please help. I am not sure how to go about resolving this. I checked the reasons for this error, while some of the content on the internet gave me some clue. But I am not clear enough to resolve this.